# phpMyAdmin can't find tmp directory

Tags: apache, database, phpmyadmin

I have a site hosted with BlueHost. I need to upload a rather large SQL file to the *tmp* directory so I can run an import.

However, phpMyAdmin is giving me the following error:

> The directory you set for upload work cannot be reached

It's trying to reach the directory `/home/site_name/tmp` when the "site_name" directory doesn't exist. The actual path should just be `/home/site/tmp`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Obvious thoughts: can you create that directory? can you edit phpmyadmin's configuration to use a different temp directory (either from the phpmyadmin interface or by tweaking your config.inc.php file?).

Comment: Is this phpmyadmin you installed yourself or provided by BlueHost? If it's provided, just lodge a ticket with them - they should be able to fix it for you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use their shared hosting plan, you should check if the path of phpMyAdmin is on same location of the folder you set with the file.

Make sure to check the permissions of that folder and if it's not have conflict since tmp folder can be used by another script or software that run on the server.

If it still not work for you, I would suggest to contact with BlueHost.